# Kids with telekinetic powers in a quarantined city (written by female author)

Tags: story-identification, novel

I have been looking for this little sci-fi novel I read as a kid in the late 90's. By that time it already was pretty old.

I don't remember the storyline, but it was set in a quarantined city (I think in the US), the main character was a young female, some kids in the city had developed telekinetic powers, there was this cripple who also had powers and was somehow significant to the story. The title *maybe* include the words "children" and "light", but I didn't find anything.

It is a short book and probably not well known.

Appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Children of Morrow by H.MHoover?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got it! "Sunburst" by Phyllis Gotlieb!

After reading through half of [this list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_science_fiction_authors), I recognized the title (the german version of this wikipedia article also lists best known work). I ordered it right away (used, but who cares), man I cannot wait. Nostalgia ahoy!

For anyone interested, a short introduction:

> A nuclear accident ravages a small town outside of Chicago, resulting
>   in a government quarantine isolating it from the rest of the world. A
>   generation later, with the quarantine still in place, strange
>   mutations have affected the minds of the town's children -- mutations
>   which could either spell the next stage in human evolution, or
>   something far more sinister. As the children's psychic powers begin to
>   manifest themselves in more demented and destructive forms, the kids
>   escape their compound. Now it is up to Shandy Johnson and her friends
>   to track down the runaways. Possessing similar powers, Sandy and her
>   friends find themselves facing increasingly frightening confrontations
>   with their escaped peers. First published in 1964 and again in 1978,
>   Sunburst has lost neither its edge nor its relevance. Predating the
>   near-misses and disasters at Three Mile Island and Chernobyl, Gotlieb
>   reminds us of the tremendous forces we have at our fingertips --
>   powers that humans use daily but do not fully comprehend

PS I asked this question as a guest, is there any way to merge accounts or something?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts

Comment: @SeanDuggan Should have googled that. Thanks for the link

Comment: Thanks for the info - still waiting for a respond to the merging request

Answer (score 5):

This may be a bit off from what you are asking, but your question brought this to mind

[This Silver Sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Silver_Sequence) by Cliff McNish.

> The Silver Sequence concerns 6 children with unusual powers: Tom (a ‘giver of beauty,’) Walter (a giant), twin girls Freda and Alice, and Milo, a boy who finally turns into a being with silver wings seven miles long. The story concerns the effort of these children to stop a single vast entity from destroying all life on Earth – an entity known only by the terrifying noise it makes: the Roar.

If I remember correctly, they are confined in a wasteland where only children with powers can go, a forcefield was pushing out the parents. I believe Milo may be something akin to crippled, I remember he couldn't really do anything, and he is very significant to the story.

Comment: There are similarities, but yes, that's not the one I'm looking for. Thanks for the suggestion though!